# Вижу ссылки в combo box (Java) не понимаю откуда они могут взятся

Tags: java

Всем добрый вечер.

В вариантах выбора comboBox в Java, вижу вот такую белиберду. Откуда она может взяться? Что это? Ссылки? Указатели (которых в java нету)?

[image: Скриншот]

Сам код.

```
private int dSize;
private JImageDisplay display;
private FractalGenerator frac;
private Rectangle2D.Double range;
private JButton saveButton;
private JButton resetButton;
private JComboBox <FractalGenerator> myComboBox;

/**
 * Конструктор класса FractalExplorer
 */

public FractalExplorer(int size){
    dSize = size;
frac = new Mandelbrot();
    range = new Rectangle2D.Double();
    frac.getInitialRange(range);
    display = new JImageDisplay(dSize, dSize);
}

/**
 *Представление графического интерфейса для пользователя.
 */

 public void createAndShowGUI(){
    display.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JFrame myframe = new JFrame("Fractal Explorer");
    myframe.add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset Display");
    ResetHandler handler = new ResetHandler();
    resetButton.addActionListener(handler);
    myframe.add(resetButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    MouseHandler click = new MouseHandler();
    display.addMouseListener(click);

    myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    myComboBox = new JComboBox<FractalGenerator>();


    FractalGenerator mandelbrotFractal = new Mandelbrot();
    myComboBox.addItem(mandelbrotFractal);
    FractalGenerator tricornFractal = new Tricorn();
    myComboBox.addItem(tricornFractal);
    FractalGenerator burningShipFractal = new BurningShip();
    myComboBox.addItem(burningShipFractal);


    ButtonHandler fractalChooser = new ButtonHandler();
    myComboBox.addActionListener(fractalChooser);
}
```

**Обновление**

@Вадим Спасибо огромное. Сделал вот таким образом.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
Class c1 = this.getClass();
return c1.getName();
}
```

Действительно получилось. Но такой вопрос. Нигде этот метод я сам не вызывал,следовательно при добавление в ComboBox он вызывается самостоятельно? Верно?

Answer (score 1):

Да это ссылка на объект, попробуйте переопределить метод

```
@Override
public String toString()
   return "То что надо видеть в списке";
}
```

в классе объекты которого вы заносите в комбобокс, у вас - FractalGenerator

Comment: Действительно получилось. Но такой вопрос. Нигде этот метод я сам не вызывал,следовательно при добавление в ComboBox он вызывается самостоятельно? Верно?`@Override
public String toString()
{
Class c1 = this.getClass();
return c1.getName();
}`

Comment: Да этот метод вызывается при попытки конвертации объекта в строку, например при выводе в консоль или как у вас при отображении в списках или таблицах.

Comment: у себы вы можете еще проще написать return getName(); (или даже подозреваю просто return name;) так как вам нет необходимости в "с" возвращать класс, вы и так в нем.